# Limit how frequently a function is called, returning a cached value in the mean time

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I have a service that handles many (~100K) requests per second. Before each request, it checks (for example) if it's started raining, and if so, the behavior changes:

```
if(IsRaining())
    return "You probably shouldn't go anywhere today.";
//... otherwise proceed
```

**IsRaining Version 1 (Slowest)**

```
public bool IsRaining() => ExternalService.IsRaining();
```

In trying to speed up my service I discovered that checking `Service.IsRaining` is the performance bottleneck.

---

I decided I didn't care if the status *only just changed* to "raining", I could cache the result for a small time. (With a slight exception - if it stops raining, I want to know immediately).

I solved that using the following approach:

**IsRaining Version 2 (Faster)**

```
bool isRainingCache;
public bool IsRaining()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UTCNow;
    // If the last time we checked, it was raining, make sure it still is. OR
    // If it hasn't been raining, only check again if we haven't checked in the past second.
    if (isRainingCache || (now - lastChecked) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    {
        isRainingCache = ExternalService.IsRaining();
        lastChecked = now;
    }
    return isRainingCache;
}
```

This made things a lot faster and worked for a long time. Then, my service got even faster, it started getting called **hundreds** of thousands of times per second, and benchmarking informed me that calling `DateTime.Now` so much makes up 50% of all CPU time.

I know what you're thinking:

> Is calling `DateTime.Now` really your bottleneck?

I'm pretty sure it is. I'm calling it hundreds of thousands of times per second. My real service is just a wrapper for a hash-map lookup - calls are meant to be very fast.

---

My next thought is that rather than checking how long it's been every single call, some timer could asynchronously **expire** the cached result after some time:

**IsRaining Version 3 (Fastest?)**

```
bool? isRainingCache = null;
public bool IsRaining()
{
    // Only check for rain if the cache is empty, or it was raining last time we checked.
    if (isRainingCache == null || isRainingCache == true)
    {
        isRainingCache = ExternalService.IsRaining();
        // If it's not raining, force us to check again after 1 second
        if(!isRainingCache)
            Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(() => { isRainingCache = null; }));
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above (untested) would speed things along, but I feel like this leaves me with several new problems:

- It feels abusive to "fire and forget" a `Task` like this (especially as often as once per second).
- If my service is disposed or finalized, I would be leaving queued tasks lying around. I feel like I need to hold on to the task or a cancellation token.
- I'm generally inexperienced with TPL, but I feel like it's not appropriate to use `Timer`s or `Thread`s here, which in my experience can lead to a myriad of other shutdown and cleanup issues.

---

If anyone has any suggestions for a better approach, I would be very appreciative.

I've got several cases like this, I'm thinking it would be nice to abstract the solution into it's own wrapper class, something like:

```
// Calls the getter at most once per 1000 ms, returns a cached value otherwise.
public Throttled<bool> IsRaining = new Throttled<bool>(() => Service.IsRaining, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to use `Environment.TickCount`, you should notice a speedup. This is probably going to be the cheapest timer you can check.

@Fabjan's answer may be better, though, if you truly are seeing this method hit 100,000 times a second.

```
bool isRainingCache;
int lastChecked = Environment.TickCount - 1001;

public bool IsRaining()
{
    int now = Environment.TickCount;
    // If the last time we checked, it was raining, make sure it still is. OR
    // If it hasn't been raining, only check again if we haven't checked in the past second.
    if (isRainingCache || unchecked(now - lastChecked) > 1000)
    {
        isRainingCache = ExternalService.IsRaining();
        lastChecked = now;
    }
    return isRainingCache;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most effective solution.

Comment: Thanks Cory - I shared my final approach below, but this was the heart of the performance improvement. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple rewrite to use Stopwatch instead of DateTime.Now reduces the overhead (for this isolated part) quite significantly.

*(since another answer here posted `Environment.TickCount` I added it for completeness and it has the lowest overhead of them all, note that this value has a turnover rate around 24-25 days before it goes negative so any solution would need to take that into account, note that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373434/267) by [@Cory Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209199/cory-nelson) does that, it uses `unchecked` to make sure the subtraction works.)*

```
void Main()
{
    BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly).RunAll();
}

public class Benchmarks
{
    private DateTime _Last = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime _Next = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
    private Stopwatch _Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    private int _NextTick = Environment.TickCount + 1000;

    [Benchmark]
    public void ReadDateTime()
    {
        bool areWeThereYet = DateTime.Now >= _Last.AddSeconds(1);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ReadDateTimeAhead()
    {
        bool areWeThereYet = DateTime.Now >= _Next;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ReadStopwatch()
    {
        bool areWeThereYet = _Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ReadEnvironmentTick()
    {
        bool areWeThereYet = Environment.TickCount > _NextTick;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
              Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
-------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
        ReadDateTime | 220.958 ns | 4.3334 ns | 4.8166 ns |
   ReadDateTimeAhead | 214.025 ns | 0.8364 ns | 0.7414 ns |
       ReadStopwatch |  25.365 ns | 0.1805 ns | 0.1689 ns |
 ReadEnvironmentTick |   1.832 ns | 0.0163 ns | 0.0153 ns |
```

So a simple change to this should reduce the overhead for this *isolated* part of your code:

```
bool isRainingCache;
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
public bool IsRaining()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    // If the last time we checked, it was raining, make sure it still is. OR
    // If it hasn't been raining, only check again if we haven't checked in the past second.
    if (isRainingCache || stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000)
    {
        isRainingCache = ExternalService.IsRaining();
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }
    return isRainingCache;
}
```

Comment: Not only is it faster, but it's more correct, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372776/limit-how-frequently-a-function-is-called-returning-a-cached-value-in-the-mean/50373368?noredirect=1#comment87763348_50372776).

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks. Switching to Stopwatch or TickCount certainly looks like it would hammer down the nail enough that I wouldn't have to complicate the solution drastically with the addition of async / threading.

Comment: If you compare with stopwatch, I think it's a bit more honest to compare with `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()`.

Comment: There's all sorts of ways to get a value that corresponds to "time served" for the CPU, such as bumping down to the `RDTSC` counter. In my opinion it's also important to be able to actually explain the purpose of the code and how it works. If you're going down to `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` which is a static method with no documentation to the resolution of the values you get back, I am not sure I could recommend that. Still, something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that DateTime.Now call is a bottleneck of application indicates that something might be wrong with the architecture. What's possible wrong here is that we're updating the cache *inside* of a method that should only get the latest value and return it. If we split up updating the cache and method to get the latest value we'd get something along the lines of:

```
const int UpdateCacheInterval = 300;

// we use keyword volatile as we access this variable from different threads
private volatile bool isRainingCache;

private Task UpdateCacheTask { get; set; }
// Use it to cancel background task when it's requred
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void InitializeCache()
{
   UpdateCacheTask = Task.Run(async () => 
   {
      while(!CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
         await Task.Delay(UpdateCacheInterval);
         isRainingCache = ExternalService.IsRaining();
      }
   }, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

public bool IsRaining()
{
    // set the UpdateCacheInterval to a short interval where it's not possible
    // that one second has expired from the time of the last check
    return isRainingCache;
}

// To stop the task execution
public async Task Stop()
{
    CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();        
    await UpdateCacheTask; 
}
```

> I'm generally inexperienced with TPL, but I feel like it's not
>   appropriate to use Timers or Threads here, which in my experience can
>   lead to a myriad of other shutdown and cleanup issues

It's perfectly fine to use timers and threads here because we need some backgroundworker to update the cache.

Comment: One of the biggest problems here is that you're doing the work *even when requests are not coming in for the required value*.

Comment: @Servy True but if the number of requests a second is *that* big that `DateTime.Now` call has become a bottleneck it shouldn't be that much of a problem here.

Comment: Presumably the performance problems due to high usage are peak usage, not *constant* usage.

Comment: @Servy Then we have a question of distribution of calls: whether it's a few millions of calls in 10 mins and then 23 hours of silence or it's 50 millions of calls a day evenly distributed... It depends on too many things we don't know...

Comment: @Servy is correct, usage is bursty, but I still appreciate this suggestion. I wonder if there's a way to "spin down" this thread and simply have the first call to "IsRaining" after a while take a little longer?

Comment: Apparently [the use commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372776/limit-how-frequently-a-function-is-called-returning-a-cached-value-in-the-mean/50373368?noredirect=1#comment87761740_50372776) that they don't want to do precisely this because apparently there is enough downtime that it needs to not be doing these calls in said downtime, so they've made that judgement call.

Comment: Quick question: how would I correctly dispose of this? For example, on shutdown, "ExternalService" will be finalized, I imagine if this task fires after it has been finalized, but before the garbage collector has gotten around to clearing up this task, there will be hell to pay.

Comment: @Alain Updated my answer

Comment: I feel like this is only running once. Do I need a while loop in that task to keep it running? Or should I be re-invoke the task on each call to `IsRaining()` (with duplicate invocations being ignored)?

Comment: @Alain Yep, sorry, it's a typo... It should have been 'while' loop not 'if', updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Fabjan. My original question sought performance, and I believe your solution would be the most performant. I did opt for a solution with less complexity in the end (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376578/529618), so my accepted answer reflects that, but I wish I could accept this one as well since it's arguably what other people in this situation should be aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the different approaches. If anyone is curious, I did end up abstracting this functionality into a re-usable class, so I can go:

```
private static readonly Throttled<bool> ThrottledIsRaining =
    new Throttled<bool>(ExternalService.IsRaining, 1000);

public static bool IsRaining()
{
    bool cachedIsRaining = ThrottledIsRaining.Value;
    // This extra bit satisfies my special case - bypass the cache while it's raining
    if (!cachedIsRaining) return false;
    return ThrottledIsRaining.ForceGetUpdatedValue();
}
```

---

```
/// <summary>Similar to <see cref="Lazy{T}"/>. Wraps an expensive getter
/// for a value by caching the result and only invoking the supplied getter
/// to update the value if the specified cache expiry time has elapsed.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of underlying value.</typeparam>
public class Throttled<T>
{
    #region Private Fields
    /// <summary>The time (in milliseconds) we must to cache the value after
    /// it has been retrieved.</summary>
    private readonly int _cacheTime;

    /// <summary>Prevent multiple threads from updating the value simultaneously.</summary>
    private readonly object _updateLock = new object();

    /// <summary>The function used to retrieve the underlying value.</summary>
    private readonly Func<T> _getValue;

    /// <summary>The cached result from the last time the underlying value was retrieved.</summary>
    private T _cachedValue;

    /// <summary>The last time the value was retrieved</summary>
    private volatile int _lastRetrieved;
    #endregion Private Fields

    /// <summary>Get the underlying value, updating the result if the cache has expired.</summary>
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            int now = Environment.TickCount;
            // If the cached value has expired, update it
            if (unchecked(now - _lastRetrieved) > _cacheTime)
            {
                lock (_updateLock)
                {
                    // Upon acquiring the lock, ensure another thread didn't update it first.
                    if (unchecked(now - _lastRetrieved) > _cacheTime)
                        return ForceGetUpdatedValue();
                }
            }
            return _cachedValue;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Construct a new throttled value getter.</summary>
    /// <param name="getValue">The function used to retrieve the underlying value.</param>
    /// <param name="cacheTime">The time (in milliseconds) we must to cache the value after
    /// it has been retrieved</param>
    public Throttled(Func<T> getValue, int cacheTime)
    {
        _getValue = getValue;
        _cacheTime = cacheTime;
        _lastRetrieved = unchecked(Environment.TickCount - cacheTime);
    }

    /// <summary>Retrieve the current value, regardless of whether
    /// the current cached value has expired.</summary>
    public T ForceGetUpdatedValue()
    {
        _cachedValue = _getValue();
        _lastRetrieved = Environment.TickCount;
        return _cachedValue;
    }

    /// <summary>Allows instances of this class to be accessed like a normal
    /// <typeparamref name="T"/> identifier.</summary>
    public static explicit operator T(Throttled<T> t) => t.Value;
}
```

I decided to minimize expiry check time using @CoryNelson's [unckecked `TickCount` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373434/529618). While using an asynchronous expiry mechanism should be faster, I found it not worth the complexity of maintaining additional disposable resources and worrying about additional threading and cleanup issues.

I also took into account @Servy's [warning about race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372776/limit-how-frequently-a-function-is-called-returning-a-cached-value-in-the-mean/50373368?noredirect=1#comment87764288_50372776) that might arise when multiple threads access the same throttled value. The addition of a lock avoids unnecessarily updating the value more than once within the expiry window.

Let me know if you think I missed anything. Thanks everyone.

Comment: There's no synchronization around the reading of `_cachedValue`, which could result in either out of date or even entirely incorrect values being read from it.  Reading/writing to a variable is not a safe and atomic operation.

Comment: I think in this case it's logically sound because it's a *cached* value, it's expected behavior to get an out-of-date version, even if in theory it *just* expired. That being said, I might need more information on what you mean by "entirely incorrect values being read". Are you suggesting that if `T` is, say, an `Int64` - and the assignment `_cachedValue = _getValue();` is happening on one thread just as `return _cachedValue;` happens on another thread, the resulting value returned might be something other than the old value or the new value?

Comment: It can be more than just slightly out of date though.  It can *never update* because there's nothing forcing it to ever observe changes made from another thread.  As for the wrong value, yes, exactly that.  It's possible for one thread to write the first half of the bits, another thread read the value when only half of the bits were overwritten, and then for the first thread to write the second half of the bits.  The result being the second thread observed a value that was never assigned to the variable.

Comment: Follow-up question (assuming thread safety is in fact a concern), is there a lean `many-can-read-or-one-can-write-lock` I can use that doesn't block multiple threads from reading the value simultaneously, but blocks them IFF the value is being written?

Comment: Re: Observing changes from another thread, I thought non-volatile properties were *eventually consistent* across threads. Is it really possible for one or more threads to never see the update?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using `Lazy`, which is specifically designed to solve the problem of a value being created once and then read by all of the threads that might need it.  Your situation is different in that you won't need just one, so you'd need to build on it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible for it to never see the update.  It needs to come across some mechanism, such as a memory barrier, to prevent such a thing.  This is almost always done via locking however.

Comment: Is it sufficient that in my case `_lastRetrieved` is volatile? Since every thread is checking `_lastRetrieved` before deciding whether to return the cached value, and `_cachedValue` is updated from within the `_updateLock` - wouldn't that ensure that all threads have their `_cachedValue` up to date since it was assigned form within that memory barrier?

Comment: That won't compile, because only certain types can be made volatile (those that support the guarantees needed for it to work).